# Permutation of treatment and control groups in R program

Tags: r

I would like to do blocked randomization for 120 participants into 40 blocks of 3 participants each. 2 participants within each block is assigned to treatment (denoted by 1) and 1 participant is assigned to control (denoted by 0).

I want to randomize the numbers (1, 1, 0) within each block using R program.
To generate the numbers i used

> n00=1
>
> n11=2
>
> labels = rep(c(rep(0,n00), rep(1,n11)),40)

How do i randomize the numbers in blocks of 3 so that there are 2 1's and 1 0's?

Answer (score 1):

**Comment.** I don't see any randomization in your code.
There are three possibilities in the assignment of two subjects
out of three to treatment and the other to control: $(1,1,0), (1,0,1),
(0,1,1).$

The R function `sample` uses a random number generator to do random sampling. The following R code will randomly provide one of these three assignments at a time.

If you use the same seed at the start as I did, you will get exactly
the same output as I did. For unexpected results, you can let R select
an unknown seed.

```
set.seed(914)
sample(c(0,1,1), 3)
[1] 0 1 1
sample(c(0,1,1), 3)
[1] 0 1 1
sample(c(0,1,1), 3)
[1] 1 0 1
sample(c(0,1,1), 3) 
[1] 1 0 1
sample(c(0,1,1), 3)
[1] 1 0 1
sample(c(0,1,1), 3)
[1] 1 1 0
```

The following R program will make a matrix `MAT` of assignments for 20 blocks. (Read down columns.) 
You can change `20` to `40`.

Of course, in order for this
to make sense, you have to assign in advance numbers 1-20 to blocks and numbes
1-3 to people within blocks.

```
set.seed(2019)
MAT = replicate(20, sample(c(0,1,1), 3));  MAT

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    0     1     1 
[2,]    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1     1     0
[3,]    0    1    1    0    1    1    1    0    1     0     1
     [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     1
[2,]     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
[3,]     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
```